# Проблема с кавычками шаблонизатора в динамических ссылках

Tags: php, laravel, шаблонизаторы, blade

Учу лару, делал по этому [уроку](https://youtu.be/joF3QuA0_gY?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFX3vIw4mSilTVihgL98y3e4)

Есть такой роут

```
Route::get('/webazex/{{id}}', 'OrderFormController@getOrderId')->name('order-id');
```

В контроллере такой код, для этого роута

```
public function getOrderId(){
        $order = new Order;
        return view('order', array(
           'order' => $order->find($id),
        ));
    }
```

Вывожу все это в шаблонизаторе Blade вот так

```
<div class="order">
        <h3>{{$item->subject}}</h3>
        <h4>{{$item->fio}}</h4>
        <a href="tel:{{$item->tel}}">{{$item->tel}}</a>
        <a href="mail:{{$item->email}}">{{$item->email}}</a>
        <p>{{$item->desc}}</p>
        <span>{{$item->created_at}}</span>
        <a href="{{route('order-id', $item->id)}}"><span>Заказ</span></a>
    </div>
```

Вот тут `$item->id` приходит именно `1`, проверял
На выходе получаю это:

```
<div class="order">
        <h3>Разработка сайта</h3>
        <h4>Антон</h4>
        <a href="tel:0680658422">0680658422</a>
        <a href="mail:webazex@gmail.com">webazex@gmail.com</a>
        <p>вапвапвапвапвапваврпвап</p>
        <span>2021-01-06 09:22:14</span>
        <a href="http://lara.loc/webazex/1%7D"><span>Заказ</span></a>
    </div>
```

где `1` - это то что мне нужно, а `%7D` это:

[image: скрин с сайта]

Подскажите как это можно пофиксить, и если есть возможность сделать это как то лучше - тоже буду благодарен, если кто посоведует годный туториал из своего опыа изучения этого фреймворка - могу даже задонатить)
Версия Laravel - последняя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас лишняя фигурная скобка в параметре роута:

Должно быть:

```
Route::get('/webazex/{id}', 'OrderFormController@getOrderId')->name('order-id');
```

Подробнее о роутинге с параметрами https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters